# Drawing/Math/Programming trouble

Tags: c#, math, drawing, geometry

I'm trying to draw a line with varying thickness bounded by a rectangle of varying size and width.  I don't know where else to go besides the geniuses here at Stack Overflow.

The top two rectangles is how it should look, and the bottom rectangle is the problem with my current code.  The pen width here is 100.  You can see on the bottom rectangle that the starting X point for the thick line is too far to the right, it's supposed to just touch the thin outer rectangle.  [image]

Here is my code:

```
if (size.Width < size.Height)
{
if (pen.Width >= size.Width)
    sizeRatio = 0.5;
else if (pen.Width >= size.Height)
    sizeRatio = 0.0;
else sizeRatio = (size.Height - pen.Width) / ((Double)size.Width - pen.Width) / 2.0;

    Double penWidthSquared = pen.Width * pen.Width;
    Double xPoint = Math.Sqrt(sizeRatio * penWidthSquared) / 2.0;
    Double yPoint = Math.Sqrt((1.0 - sizeRatio) * penWidthSquared) / 2.0;

    Point startPoint = new Point(location.X + (Int32)xPoint, location.Y + (Int32)yPoint);
    Point endPoint = new Point(location.X + size.Width - (Int32)xPoint, location.Y + size.Height - (Int32)yPoint);
    graphics.DrawLine(pen, startPoint, endPoint);
}
```

I don't quite understand why the pythagorean theorem doesn't work, maybe I'm doing it wrong.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've been stuck on this for days!

Comment: Can you post a diagram of what you want? And startpoint in 2nd example 35,35 is for white rectangle or black? Also provide the desired start and end points of the third rectangle.

Comment: Also your calculations in the above figure are wrong. I mean `(100^2)/1^0.5 = 100` should be either `((100^2)/1)^0.5 = 100` or `(100^2)/1^0.5 = 10000`. And `((100^2)/2)^0.5 = 70` should be `((100^2)/2)^0.5 = 100/sqrt(2) = 70.71`

Comment: I'm looking for the start and end points for the thick black lines.  (0, 50)  For the first line in the image and (35, 35) for the second. The third line starting and ending point is unknown and I don't know how to calculate it...

Comment: I don't understand what is your actual problem? Also I will be available after 17 hours on this site. If you can then please become online after 17 hours and send me some indication that you are online.